# Why does the probabilistic method work to obtain bounds?

Tags: probability, expectation

In the following problem, the probabilistic method is used to obtain a lower bound.

$15$ chipmunks live in $52$ circularly arranged trees. Show there must be a neighborhood of $7$ trees that houses at least three chipmunks. 

Let $X$ denote the number of chipmunks living in the neighbohood of a randomly chosen tree. Let $X_i$ equal $1$ iff chipmunk $i$ lives in the neighborhood of said tree. Then
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{15}\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\frac {15\cdot 7}{52} > 2 $$
My question is: why does this work?

I believe that here, we are trying to obtain the minimum number achievable, in other words, we are trying to obtain the lower bound for $\min f(x)$ where $f$ counts the number of chipmunks living in the neighborhood of a tree. Yet, I do not see how the expected value serves this purpose. I can see how the expected value can bound the maximum from below and the minimum from above, but I cannot see how to bound them from above and below, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a discrete variable $Y$ and we know that $E(Y)>a$, then we automatically know that $P(Y > a)>0$. That is, there exists some value $b>a$ with positive probability: $P(Y=b)>0$

In your case: $E(X)>2 \implies P(X>2)>0$, then there exists some $b \in \{3, 4 \cdots \} $ with $P(X=b)>0$, then there exists "a neighborhood of $7$ trees that houses at least three chipmunks".

Comment: But how do we know that there must be such a configuration? I understand that the probability must be nonzero but I do not see how this implies that it must be a certainty

Comment: Recall that the configuration is fixed (not random), the only randomness is the chossing of the tree. If all trees in the configuration were "sparse" (no $7-$ neighborhood with more than $2$ chipmunks) then $P(X>2)=0$.

Comment: If you still have douts you could write the prob as a marginal over the chosen tree: $P(X>2)=\sum_{t=1}^{52} P(X>2 \cap T=t)=\sum_{t=1}^{52} P(X>2 \mid T=t)\frac{1}{52}$